# Non-derogatory term similar to "inflexible"

Tags: single-word-requests, nonsubjective

I'm looking for a word that's somewhat similar to *inflexible*, but non-derogatory, used to describe a characteristic of a person or their habits.

For example, let's say we have someone who really cares about their oral health. He brushes his teeth on time shortly after every meal and tries to keep his teeth-brushing to no more than three times daily because he believes brushing too much is harmful to the teeth. As a result, he tries to avoid snacking whenever possible. So, he doesn't take any snack beverage or any food like chocolate, chips, coffee, fries, etc. outside of his three main meals during his commute or at social gatherings, parties, etc. even when offered. When offered he will politely refuse or save them for later until a main meal.

Now, this is not necessarily a bad thing. His behaviour shows that he is a pretty [...] person, or he is being pretty [...] about his oral health?

Comment: General Reference/Not Constructive. Google [synonym inflexible](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=synonym+inflexible&oq=synonym+inflexible&aqs=chrome.0.57.714j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and work outwards from there. When you find words like *steadfast, staunch, resolute, adamant* (which you surely will), Google synonyms of those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While "inflexible" may be a component the traits you describe, you are not really looking for a synonym of "inflexible". The person you describe can be said to be **disciplined** or **regimented**.

Both words connote a regular and strict conformity to a course of behavior. They are often used to illustrate that the behavior is for the person's overall benefit. This might be the case even while there may be some negative consequences, the least of which may simply be the lack of flexibility that their regimen allows.

Comment: ooops!  Sorry @Jim, I didn't see you'd already suggested "regimented".  I'll close my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A neutral word that comes to mind is [adamant](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/adamant).

Answer (score 1):

I feel this might not be what you are looking for, but the first words that came to my mind are "Methodic" and "self-disciplined".

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[consistent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistent#Adjective)*, “Of a regularly occurring, dependable nature.”    This is less-judgemental than some of the previously-suggested words.  If you don't mind a word that is somewhat more judgemental, consider  *[prissy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prissy#Adjective)*, “excessively prim, proper, particular or fussy”.

Answer (score 1):

Firm. Adamant. Strong. Resolute. Uncompromising.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.

Comment: @MετάEd omit needless words.

Comment: I don't always like the results of the autoflagger but it is usually right. On one hand this answer is accurate and succinct. On the other hand it lacks any kind of explanation or citations.

Comment: This answer doesn't require citations.  It's common knowledge

Answer (score 1):

**Scrupulous.** 
http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrupulous

It tends to have a positive ring but also tells the listener that the person is **rigorous**, **meticulous** and extremely **vigilant** over his dental care.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/meticulous?showCookiePolicy=true

> But his trademark is **meticulous** planning and attention to detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to categorize the person, "staunch" is your go-to.  As in "staunch liberal".

Comment: Two things: one, this doesn't seem to fit in the proposed sentences:  he's a staunch person?  He's staunch about his oral health?  Two, can you add more detail like a definition (and its source) that show how it's a decent fit?

Answer (score 0):

- rigid
- regimented
- “set in his ways”
- anal-retentive

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: @ibf common knowledge does not require citations, but I surely will where warranted.  I'm curious why you chose to leave that comment on this answer and none of the others?

Comment: forum guidelines ... and your answer was placed in my queue.